# How to automate the Spotfire Dashboard into Excel output?

Tags: spotfire

The Spotfire Dashboard Data has to be automated into excel output to the end users. Upon checking i could see there scripts usage to perform the same, but not able to find a proper solution to achieve it.

Your responses and guidance to the same is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, this isn't built into Spotfire but you could do it with some custom coding and the Spotfire API. What is available is automated export as PDF or JPG. You'll want to read up on [Spotfire Automation Services](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/spotfire-automation-services/7.6.0/doc/pdf/TIB_sfire_autsvcs_7.6.0_user_manual.pdf).

Comment: Thanks a lot simon for your response.